# Failing to find script-runner.jar

Tags: python, boto, amazon-emr

Here's the code to install and run hive over EMR

```
args = ['s3://' + zone_name + '.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script',
    '--base-path', 's3://' + zone_name + '.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/',
    '--install-hive', '--hive-versions', '0.13.1']

args2 = ['s3://' + zone_name + '.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script',
     '--base-path', 's3://' + zone_name + '.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/',
     '--hive-versions', '0.13.1',
     '--run-hive-script', '--args',
     '-f', s3_url]

steps = []
for name, args in zip(('Setup Hive', 'Run Hive Script'), (args, args2)):
    step = JarStep(name,
               's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
               step_args=args,
               # action_on_failure="CANCEL_AND_WAIT"
               )
# should be inside loop
    steps.append(step)
```

Now when i feed this to run_jobflow, for some reason

i get error

`Error fetching jar file. java.lang.RuntimeException: Error whilst fetching 's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar`

I can access bucket `elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/` with my credentials. How can i resolve this?Or is there any other way `script-runner` can be provided

Comment: In what region is the emr cluster running on ?

Comment: @jcmannem same useast1

Comment: ok. Well, EMR uses EMR_EC2_DefaultRole which is instance profile role's  cred's to access the buckets from your cluster. Does that role has any denys  on it policy to block access ? Also, is there more to that error  on your step logs ?

Comment: I solved this for the case of the Java SDK, hopefully it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/56541531/1586965

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your cluster being in a different region than the bucket you a fetching the jar from. Make sure that the EMR cluster is in the same region that you are passing as "zone_name".