# Java SDK AWS EMR gives Failed to download error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

If you follow

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html

and you are not in us-east-1 then you'll get

```
2019-06-11T08:39:00.283Z INFO Ensure step 1 jar file s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar
INFO Failed to download: s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error whilst fetching 's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar'
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.fetchS3HadoopFileToLocal(S3Wrapper.java:412)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.fetchHadoopFileToLocal(S3Wrapper.java:351)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.HadoopJarStepRunner$Runner.<init>(HadoopJarStepRunner.java:243)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.HadoopJarStepRunner.createRunner(HadoopJarStepRunner.java:152)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.HadoopJarStepRunner.createRunner(HadoopJarStepRunner.java:146)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.StepExecutor.runStep(StepExecutor.java:136)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.StepExecutor.run(StepExecutor.java:70)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.StepExecutionManager.enqueueStep(StepExecutionManager.java:246)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.StepExecutionManager.doRun(StepExecutionManager.java:193)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.StepExecutionManager.access$000(StepExecutionManager.java:33)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.master.steprunner.StepExecutionManager$1.run(StepExecutionManager.java:94)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: asdfasdf), S3 Extended Request ID: asdfasdf
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1389)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3826)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1143)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1021)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.copyS3ObjectToFile(S3Wrapper.java:303)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.getFile(S3Wrapper.java:291)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.util.S3Wrapper.fetchS3HadoopFileToLocal(S3Wrapper.java:399)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is wrong, change this line:

```
 StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();
```

To

```
StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory("<your-region>.elasticmapreduce);
```